# Jfreechart text display not working?

Tags: java, text, bar-chart, jfreechart

I,m implementing a chart to display positive negative and neutral value in it and i need to display percentages of positive, negative and neutral in the chart as a text display.

Using Bar chart in my application.

Used code

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Counts", "User Name", "Users Counts", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.GRAY);
        chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        final Marker start = new ValueMarker(60.0);
        start.setPaint(Color.red);
        start.setLabel("Current Value");
        start.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        start.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        p.addRangeMarker(start);
        p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Bar Chart", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1400, 600);
```

Comment: Maybe a `ThermometerPlot`?

Comment: Can you provide a drawing and sample data?